# How to set value for hidden field type of Umbraco form

Tags: umbraco, hidden-field

I need to set the current page name to a hidden field value of Umbraco form.
I don’t know where to give the value  for that hidden field.
Please any one share your answer. Thanks

Comment: Would you tell us how you are trying to achieve your goal. Is it Inside a macro? A Template in razor? What have you tryed soo far, please share your code so we can help you.

Comment: how it can b done in macro @GELR

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using razor...

```
<input type="hidden" value="@CurrentPage.Name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also be set in codebehind file of your Usercontrol:

- ascx.cs (usercontrol codebehind file)

Example Markup (ascx):

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="nameHiddenField" runat="server" />
```

Example Code (ascx.cs):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var helper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);

        //set value as Name of Current Node
        nameHiddenField.Value = helper.AssignedContentItem.Name;

        //set value based on a property from the Current Node
        nameHiddenField.Value = helper.AssignedContentItem.GetPropertyValue<string>("examplePropert");

        //NOTE: You may want to add some Null-Checking for when accessing Properties of the CurrentNode.
    }
```

The "UmbracoHelper" class lives in the following namespace "Umbraco.Web", so you will need to add the below:

```
using Umbraco.Web;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're using Umbraco Forms/Contour? That being the case, in the form editor, click to edit the hidden field, then expand the extra settings and you can set the default value of the hidden field there.

Comment: It should do, it's a feature of Contour, not Umbraco. I've used this feature on sites as old as 4.7. I can't remember exactly when it was added to Contour, but it was a while ago.

Comment: All i get when i add hidden input is < input type="hidden" id="sample-gui" name="sample-guid" value>